# firebase_auth_web.dart too many positional arguments

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, web, arguments

When biulding a Flutter web app connected to Firebase, the auth web has a small error en flutter_auth_web.dart, line 94.

```
static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    FirebaseCoreWeb.registerService('auth', (firebaseApp) async {
      final authDelegate = auth_interop.getAuthInstance(firebaseApp);
      // if localhost, and emulator was previously set in localStorage, use it
      if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost' && kDebugMode) {
        final String? emulatorOrigin =
            window.sessionStorage[getOriginName(firebaseApp.name)];
```

the argument for the function needs to be named, so instead it has to look like this:

```
static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
    FirebaseCoreWeb.registerService('auth', ensurePluginInitialized: (firebaseApp) async {
      final authDelegate = auth_interop.getAuthInstance(firebaseApp);
      // if localhost, and emulator was previously set in localStorage, use it
      if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost' && kDebugMode) {
        final String? emulatorOrigin =
            window.sessionStorage[getOriginName(firebaseApp.name)];
```

now it worked.

I have it already working. Problem solved

Comment: If it's solved you should add it as an answer instead of within the question. You can also verify your own answer and get reputation for both. It also helps with search results.